# How to sort Map with List by value?

Tags: java

How can I sort Map with list by value?I have in list always one element but i must use list.
I have:

```
 Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapUtil
{
    public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V>
        sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
    {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
            }
        } );

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
        {
            result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and when i try this:

```
MapUtil.sortByValue(map);
```

I get this error:

```
The method sortByValue(Map<K,V>) in the type MapUtil is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,List<String>>)
```

Answer (score 2):

`V` needs to implement comparable, but `List<String>` does not. You need to change the sorting method to use explicit [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: Could you write where and how use explicit comparator, since this example I get from stack example

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761864/java-sort-list-of-lists#answer-35761935).