# Print unique subset in lexicographic order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, subset

For my string input "aaa" I want the answer to be

```
[[],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]
```

My code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "aaa";

        char arr[] = a.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        List<List<Character>> big = new ArrayList<List<Character>>();

        subset(arr, 0, big, new ArrayList<Character>(), true);

        System.out.println(big);
    }

    static void subset(char arr[], int count, List<List<Character>> big,
                       List<Character> temp, boolean flag) {
        if (count == arr.length) {
            big.add(new ArrayList<Character>(temp));
            return;
        }
        if (flag == false && arr[count] == arr[count - 1]) {
            // logic for unique subset
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);     
        } else {
            temp.add(arr[count]);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, true);
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This code gave me this output:

```
[[a, a, a], [a, a], [a], []]
```

but I want this as:
Required output:

```
[[],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]
```

Also the logic which I wrote for getting unique subset can also be done using a collection like `TreeSet` and `HashSet`.
I tried using `TreeSet` the answer was in sorted order and unique subset but with some extra commas.
It would be really helpful if someone would solve my both problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeSet, and add a [custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367395/comparable-class-with-a-liststring-field):

```
Set<List<Character>> big = new TreeSet<>((l1, l2) -> {
    if (l1.size() != l2.size()) {
        return l1.size() - l2.size();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
        int strCmp = l1.get(i).compareTo(l2.get(i));
        if (strCmp != 0) {
            return strCmp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

And use `replaceAll("\\s+","")` to remove the extra spaces.

Everything put together:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "aaa";
        char[] arr = a.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        Set<List<Character>> big = new TreeSet<>((l1, l2) -> {
            if (l1.size() != l2.size()) {
                return l1.size() - l2.size();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
                int strCmp = l1.get(i).compareTo(l2.get(i));
                if (strCmp != 0) {
                    return strCmp;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });

        subset(arr, 0, big, new ArrayList<Character>(), true);
        custom_printing(big);
    }

    public static void custom_printing(Set<List<Character>> big){
        System.out.println(big.toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
    }

    static void subset(char[] arr, int count, Set<List<Character>> big, List<Character> temp, boolean flag) {
        if (count == arr.length) {
            big.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        }
        else if (!flag && arr[count] == arr[count - 1]) {
            // logic for unique subset
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);
        } else {
            temp.add(arr[count]);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, true);
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]
```

Or (has pointed in the comments) you can use [Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) combined with our custom_printing method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "aaa";

        char[] arr = a.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        List<List<Character>> big = new ArrayList<>();

        subset(arr, 0, big, new ArrayList<>(), true);
        Collections.reverse(big);
        custom_printing(big);
    }

    public static void custom_printing(List<List<Character>> big){
        System.out.println(big.toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
    }

    static void subset(char[] arr, int count, List<List<Character>> big,
                       List<Character> temp, boolean flag) {
        if (count == arr.length) {
            big.add(new ArrayList<Character>(temp));
            return;
        }
        if (!flag && arr[count] == arr[count - 1]) {
            // logic for unique subset
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);
        } else {
            temp.add(arr[count]);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, true);
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            subset(arr, count + 1, big, temp, false);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[[],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the overloaded method `List#add(int, T)` instead of `List#add(T)`. That way, your items will always be inserted at the beginning of the list instead of the end.

You can replace this line

`big.add(new ArrayList<Character>(temp));`

By the following

`big.add(0, new ArrayList<Character>(temp));`

And you'll get the following result

`[[], [a], [a, a], [a, a, a]]`