# Sorting HashMap <Integer, List<String>> in Java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a hashmap:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> dataA = new HashMap<>();
```

that contains data imported from Excel spreadsheet. HashMap Keys contain row numbers and HashMap Values contain lists of cell values in particular row.

Now I need to sort this by specific column (or multiple columns) from the List.

How to do that?

Comment: That would be a bad data structure for it. Move it to an array or a list and sort it. You'll have to think of things like empty rows and what to do with them.

Comment: have you tried looking at something like open csv? http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This question: [Sort a Map by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values), should maybe give you an idea

Comment: Could you provide more detail on the work you have already done or how your problem with your current solution? This is vague and comes across as a request to do your homework for you.

Comment: what you have tried so far?? Google your question, i am sure there are plenty over SO like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map<Integer, ____>` when dealing with contiguous keys is almost always the wrong choice of data structure.

```
0 -> Foo
1 -> Bar
2 -> Baz
```

Do you recognise what this is? It's literally just a list. Use a `List<List<String>>` and [it'll make your life easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761864/java-sort-list-of-lists).

Comment: OP did not state that the row numbers are contiguous or that they start at 0.

Comment: @BalzGuenat They are rows of a spreadsheet so they are kind of bound to be contiguous. You can have an empty `List<String>` if the row is empty.

Comment: @BalzGuenat It doesn't matter if they start at zero or not. Store them zero-indexed and, if you need to, then store an offset as an integer separately and add that to the index when you need to refer to the row.

Comment: Only if you insert *all* rows of the spreadsheet. Could be that they are filtered with the original row number preserved.

Comment: Or just store the original row number without messing with offsets, yes.

Comment: @BalzGuenat It's possible, but if your point is that I'm making assumptions, well now so are you, because it was never specified that the rows were filtered.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. It works perfectly fine and indeed is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

To sort hashmap contents by value part, use comparator and compare value part of hashmap instead of key part.

Following code can be used in compare method of Comparator which can be supplied to TreeMap constructor.

```
public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> o1,  
                               Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> o2) 
            { 
                return (o1.getValue().get(0)).compareTo(o2.getValue().get(0)); 
            }
```

In above code replace 0 with any of the column index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Map to be ordered, the thing to use is a TreeMap.

Then you need a class for your ordering keys, e.g. MySortKey implements Comparable<...>.

Then you need a method somewhere that can produce the appropriate MySortKey object from each List<String> that is [currently] a value in your Map.

Then you populate the TreeMap using .put(mySortKey, list) where these two variables are the MySortKey and List<String> objects.

Comment: The problem with a `TreeMap` is you need to define the comparator when you create the map. What if you want to re-order it based upon a different comparator?

Comment: Build a second map with the second comparator.

Comment: Well yes, or don't use a map in the first place.

Comment: Instead of implementing Comparable, you can also pass a Comparator to the TreeMap constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value set and sort it by a custom Comparator:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>>> comp = 
  Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e) -> e.getValue().get(firstColumnIndex))
            .thenComparing(e -> e.getValue().get(secondColumnIndex));
List<Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>>> sorted =
  map.entrySet().stream().sorted(comp).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Didn't you imply that working with maps was easier? :D

Comment: Not easier but necessary if the keys are not 0-indexed and contiguous. This solution will work with any input map, as it makes no assumptions about the keys. (It does make an assumption about the length of the value lists, though.)